# Have pointer to data. Need Numpy array in Fortran order. Want to use Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

This is a very common use-case for me. I have a C function that returns me a pointer to doubles:

```
 //myheader.h
 double *mycfuntion(...)
```

I know the dimensions of the data that get returned. I also know that the data are **Fortran**-ordered. I want to write a Cython "shim" to get the data into Python as a Numpy array:

```
#myshim.pyx
import numpy
cimport numpy as cnumpy

cnumpy.import_array()

cdef extern from "myheader.h" :
     double *mycfunction(...)

def mypyfunc(...) :
     cdef double *data = mycfunction(...)
          **MAGIC**
     return outarray
```

---

### MAGIC ideas

**(A)** `cdef cnumpy.ndarray[ cnumpy.double_t, mode='fortran', ...] outarray` 
This would be the handiest way of doing things. There's something critical that I'm missing here, though, concerning how to turn the pointer `data` into a buffer that I can pass to the cnumpy.ndarray constructor. I've tried:

```
cdef cnumpy.ndarray[ cnumpy.double_t, mode='fortran', ...] outarray
cdef bytes databuffer = <char *>data
outarray = numpy.ndarray(buffer=databuffer, dtype=numpy.double, ...)
```

This approach consistently fails with `TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array`

**(B)** The Numpy C-API 
I've used `cnumpy.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(...)` plenty from Cython. It works just fine. The problem is that it doesn't support a *flags* argument so I can't tell it to construct a Fortran array. The alternative that I'd used in pure C implementations is `PyArray_NewFromDescr(...)`. It accepts *flags*. This approach is long-winded and painful, and means getting some symbols from numpy via an `extern` block that aren't already imported. There has got to be a better way.

---

I have been Googling my face off on this problem but nothing obvious has popped up. Maybe I'm an idiot. Or just sleep-depping. Cheers!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I would be interested in a decent answer.

Comment: Nope. I ended up sticking with `PyArray_NewFromDescr(...)`.

Comment: For future reference: I wrote my own `define`: 

`#define PyArray_SimpleNewFromDataF(nd, dims, typenum, data) PyArray_New(&PyArray_Type, nd, dims, typenum, NULL, data, 0, NPY_ARRAY_FARRAY, NULL)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a little hackish, but you can reverse the order of your dimensions then return the transpose.  This should get your striding correct, but not copy the data.

```
cimport numpy as cnp
cnp.import_array()

cdef double a1[10]
for i in range(10):
    a1[i] = i

# C order
a2 = cnp.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, [2, 5], cnp.NPY_FLOAT64, a1)
# fortran order
a3 = cnp.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, [5, 2], cnp.NPY_FLOAT64, a1).T
# a2 and a3 point to the same data
a2[0,0] = 10.
print a2
print a3
```